# Using an Android-based kiosk as an offline browser (to avoid bandwidth issues)

Tags: android, drupal, offline, rsync, kiosk

I want to use an online CMS (preferably Drupal) to create / update my website, but I also want it viewable on an Android powered kiosk as a portal to a particular website that needs to be quick (impervious to bandwidth).

The only way to do that I think is to use the kiosk as an offline browser.  What's the best way you think to do that?  I was thinking:

1) Manage my website using Drupal, which uses PHP. It's powerful, easy, free, and what I'm familiar with, and I can cripple the admin so it's safe to have less-skilled administers manage it.

2) Linux bash will do the PHP-to-HTML conversion making it offline readable, so I should be able to do this on the server with this command: *.php > *.html

3) The embedded links will still end in ".php" so I can change them to ".html" with sed command

4) pull the content to local kiosk with rsync, nightly or as needed.  (is there something better than rsync - I've had such a hard time getting it to work reliably in the past).

What do you think?  Did I miss anything?  Is there a better way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: In retrospect I think the way to do this is create an android app that scrapes the data off the drupal (or whatever website cms) site.  Android app content management is written from the outset to work with on-off connections without problems.  Bottom line, data transfer in a kiosk situation should be managed by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try Offline Browser, that allow you to download a site for offline browsing: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.nikodroid.offline

Comment: This should probably be a comment.